# super-constructor if there is no super class?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I found a class like this:

```
public class Computer implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

        //...
        public Computer() {
            super();
        }
        //...
}
```

Can someone explain me, how this works? The class isn't inheriting any super class and there could still be "super();" in the constructor?

Comment: You [inherit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) from the Object class, which has a no-arg constructor. _"In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object."_

Comment: Note that a call to a no-arg `super()` is unnecessary; it will be inserted by the compiler if you don't specify it.

Comment: java.lang.Object is the only class without a superclass, and its constructor does not contain a super() call.

Comment: I should have known this. Never imagines that someone would want to call the "Object"'s constructor. Thanks to you all. :)

Comment: Could be the result of a coding standard, some of which mandate explicit coding of implicit features, like calling super(), explicit public modifiers on interface elements, implicit private modifier on enum constructors, always prefixing instance member access with this and class member access with class name, and so on. It's not necessarily a good idea, IMO.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490875/object-class-as-super-class-in-java

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669693/advantage-of-singly-rooted-class-hierarchy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling super() with no Superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572468/calling-super-with-no-superclass)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default all classes inherit `java.lang.Object`. So a hidden code in your class is

```
public class Computer extends java.lang.Object implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

        //...
        public Computer() {
            super(); //here Object's default constructor is called
        }
        //...
}
```

If a parent class has default constructor (no argument) and if a child class defines a default constructor, then an explicit call to parent's constructor is not necessary.

Java does it implicitly, in other words, Java puts `super()` before **first statement** of the child's constructor

consider this example

```
class Base {

    public Base() {
        System.out.println("base");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

    public Derived() {
        //super(); call is not necessary.. Java code puts it here by default
        System.out.println("derived");
    }
}
```

So when you create `Derived d = new Derived();` the output is..

```
base
derived
```

Comment: Ah yeah, I know this but didn't imagine that someone would call the constructor of "Object". Does this have a reason?
Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Its mere a coding style.. if you see `Object` class has not defined a constructor - which is equivalent to defining a default constructor with empty body.. in other words, calling `super()` in your case does not yield anything

Answer (score 4):

When you do not `extends` any class then by default the inherited class is `Object` so it calls `Object` class constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `Object` class is at the top of the `Class` hierarchy. Implicitly, All the Classes are implicitly of `Object` type. Invocation of `super()` method is not needed explicitly in code. But, *this will be added by the compiler during conversion of Class into bytecode*. so, the first line in any constructor would be invocation of `super()` implicitly by default. Construction of an object includes all the invocation of default constructors of Super classes. But, you can also call a *customized argument constructor* of the `super` class in your `class` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

By default every java class implicitly inherits `java.lang.Object` class. So, `super()` will call the `Object` class constructor in your case!

Answer (score 1):

By default any class even if we don't extend any super class, extends `java.lang.Object` class. So it calls `Object` constructor.

By the inheritance concept, we can have following code compiled properly.

```
Object obj = new Computer();
```

Even, in fact, your `interface` reference can be assigned to `java.lang.Object` reference.

```
interface ICommand 
{

}
class Computer implements ICommand
{

}
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        ICommand ic = new Computer();
        Object obj = ic;  // 'ic' is an interface reference
    }
}
```

by this way, `java.lang.Object` is also super interface (this is not exact technical term ) for all interfaces.