# If we add a super() in a parent class constructor, which class will this super() invoke while creating an object of the sub class?

Tags: java, loops, inheritance

In the below example which class will the super() will call in the Shape constructor while creating an object of Square?

```
package com.company;

class Shape {
    public Shape() {
        super();
        System.out.println("inside Shape class default constructor");
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public Rectangle() {
        super();
        System.out.println("inside Rectangle class default constructor");
    }
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
    public Square() {
        super();
        System.out.println("inside Square class default constructor");
    }
}

public class Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square sq = new Square();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21181125/2988730

Answer (score 2):

It will call `java.lang.Object` class's constructor, which is the default parent of all the classes in Java.

Comment: Good answer, but please don't encourage OP to expect SO to be a homework resource.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i think this a good question. There might me a duplicate but i couldn't find it.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I found it and listed it in a comment under the question

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes I can see now, guess the page was not refreshed.